# Question about shallow copy in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, constructor

Say I have a struct "s" with an int pointer member variable "i".  I allocate memory on the heap for i in the default constructor of s.  Later in some other part of the code I pass an instance of s by value to some function.  Am I doing a shallow copy here?  Assume I didn't implement any copy constructors or assignment operators or anything for s... just the default constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To follow up on what @[don.neufeld.myopenid.com] said, it is not only a shallow copy, but it is either (take your pick) a memory leak or a dangling pointer.

```
// memory leak (note that the pointer is never deleted)
class A
{
  B *_b;
  public:
  A()
  : _b(new B)
  {
  }
};

// dangling ptr (who deletes the instance?)
class A
{
  B *_b;
  public:
  A()
  ... (same as above)

  ~A()
  {
    delete _b;
  }
};
```

To resolve this, there are several methods.

**Always implement a copy constructor and operator= in classes that use raw memory pointers.**

```
class A
{
  B *_b;
  public:
  A()
  ... (same as above)

  ~A()
  ...

  A(const A &rhs)
  : _b(new B(rhs._b))
  {
  }

  A &operator=(const A &rhs)
  {
    B *b=new B(rhs._b);
    delete _b;
    _b=b;
    return *this;
};
```

Needless to say, this is a major pain and there are quite a few subtleties to get right. I'm not even totally sure I did it right here and I've done it a few times. Don't forget you have to copy all of the members - if you add some new ones later on, don't forget to add them in too!

**Make the copy constructor and operator= private in your class.** This is the "lock the door" solution. It is simple and effective, but sometimes over-protective.

```
class A : public boost::noncopyable
{
  ...
};
```

**Never use raw pointers.** This is simple and effective. There are lots of options here:

- Use string classes instead of raw char pointers
- Use std::auto_ptr, boost::shared_ptr, boost::scoped_ptr etc

Example:

```
// uses shared_ptr - note that you don't need a copy constructor or op= - 
// shared_ptr uses reference counting so the _b instance is shared and only
// deleted when the last reference is gone - admire the simplicity!
// it is almost exactly the same as the "memory leak" version, but there is no leak
class A
{
  boost::shared_ptr<B> _b;
  public:
  A()
  : _b(new B)
  {
  }
};
```

Comment: Your assignment operator is not exception safe. See the recent question about copy and exception safety: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214891/checklist-for-writing-copy-constuctor-and-assignment-operator-in-c#214966

Comment: Doh, ok I fixed that. You see what I mean about it being a pain and hard to get right then huh

Comment: The best way to make the copy constructor and operator= private is to inherit from boost::noncopyable. You should do that for every single class unless you know for sure it will be copyable.

Comment: With the copy-and-swap idiom, it's really easy to do it right (even if it is a little inefficient)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's a shallow copy.  You now have two copies of s (one in the caller, one on the stack as a parameter), each which contain a pointer to that same block of memory.

Answer (score 2):

You will have two copies of the `s` struct, each of which will have their own `i` pointer, but both `i` pointers will have the same value pointing to the same address in memory - so yes, it will be a shallow copy.