# How to avoid memory leak during development in c

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory-leaks

Iam programming in C. I want to know what practice we should follow to avoid Memory Leaks 
at the time of development itself. Please mention the precautions to be taken specially while 
dealing with strings and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: The problem is this question would require a book to answer. Why not tell us what problem you are having and we can try to help?[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Simple. Be **VERY** careful. That should avoid any memory leaks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use variables on stack if possible rather than using memory from heap.

Try to avoid common mistakes, a few pointers:

1. Make sure to call `free()` when you use `malloc()` or `calloc()`.
2. Don't reassign pointer which points to allocated memory location without `free()`ing it first i.e. don't lose the reference.
3. Be careful when using `realloc()`. Do not use the same pointer for input & output parameters.

Avoid common mistakes made using *strings*, a few pointers:

1. Make sure there is memory for terminating `NUL` character.
2. Make sure *string* is `NUL` terminated in all your use cases (even when used in functions like `strncpy()` etc.)

Learn to use a debugger ([gdb](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/))
Learn to use static analysis tools. Tools like [splint](http://www.splint.org/), [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), [clang](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) can be installed on you linux system from your distro's package repository.

Few useful links:
[c-faq - Arrays & Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)
[c-faq - Memory allocation](http://c-faq.com/malloc/index.html)
[Secure C Coding - Memory Management](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/08.+Memory+Management+%28MEM%29)
[SO Question related to avoiding memory leak in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983216/ways-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-c-c)
[yolinux tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++MemoryCorruptionAndMemoryLeaks.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

I don't agree with down-votes on this question. I think it's a real question, and quite deep.

On the surface, the answer is "call `free` on any memory you `malloc`ed".

But the real answer is that your design should include a *clear* ownership model. The only way to avoid memory leaks and access to dangling memory is to *always* know, for every piece of dynamically allocated memory, what object owns that memory (and is responsible for disposing of it).

If you don't have such a clear ownership model, you will forever hunt memory leaks and use-after-free bugs (this also applies to C++). Use of garbage collector would allow you to plaster over these problems, at the cost of significant CPU cycles.

If you do have a clear ownership model, these problems generally just disappear: the owner `free`s all memory it owns when it itself is disposed of.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to avoid memory leak is to manually `free()` all the memory allocated by you in the during the lifetime of your code.

You can use tools such as `valgrind` to check for memory leaks. It will show all the memory that are not freed on termination of the program.

Comment: Well, Valgrind will show most of the memory that is not freed, usually.  (At least, if you're counting unreachable memory.)

Answer (score 3):

There is possibility of garbage collecting in C, in particular by using [Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/). To use it, replace `malloc` by `GC_malloc`, `strdup` by `GC_strdup` in all your program and you should not bother calling `free` or `GC_free`. Boehm's GC work verys well in practice (even if in theory there is a small probability of leakage).

Notice that being a live data is not a modular property: a given data chunk is alive in a whole program (not in a particular given module).

To answer the original question, an important issue is to define an allocation policy, and to document it. In particular, every function returning dynamically allocated data should state how, and by whom, should that data be `free`-d.

#### addenda

A useful tool to hunt memory leakage bugs in C (or C++) on Linux is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Don't forget to pass the `-g -Wall`flags to `gcc` and `g++` when developing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C programmer but generally you need to destroy or dispose of everything you are no longer using.

If you do not dispose of objects, and string are objects, then the memory may not be garbage collected and may stay resident in memory.

Comment: There's no garbage collection in c, unless you implement it yourself.

Comment: Right, so an even more compelling argument to dispose of everything no longer needed