# Ways to tell if you have successfully released dynamic allocated memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

This is how i allocate dynamic memory for a 2D array

```
char **twod;

twod=new char*[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    twod [i] = new char [MAX];
}
```

This is how i release the memory for a 2D array

```
for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
  {
      delete [] twod [i];

  }
   delete [] twod;
```

How do i know i have successfully released everything and there is no memory leak???

Comment: You could always just use RAII and have a much lower probability of a memory leak occurring to start with.

Comment: *"How do i know i have successfully released everything and there is no memory leak???"* - Because you have called `delete []` for everything you used `new []` to allocate.  And what @chris said.

Comment: `This is how i allocate dynamic memory for a 2D array` I am sorry to hear that. Be sure to take your pills...

Comment: What chris said.  Prevention is better than cure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/959708/24283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Ways to tell if you have successfully released dynamic allocated memory**

Run the code in valgrind or any such memory leak detection tool.
If you want you could also overload the `new` and `delete` operators for your class and do the bookeeping yourself but that it too much effort so you are much better off setting with a memory leak detection tool.

Ofcourse I consider the example only an sample example and not the code one will usually go for because:

1. You are better off avoiding dynamic allocations, use automatic variables instead.
2. If you must then use smart pointers with RAII and not raw pointers.